# Strange behaviour default constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, overloading, default

Can someone explain me why in the overloading function after temp is created, temp.x becomes 2, and temp.y becomes 1 ? The default constructor has no arguments therefore shouldn't temp.x and temp.y be 0 or have a weird number ?
Thank you!

```
// overloading operators example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CVector {
  public:
    int x,y;
    CVector () {};
    CVector (int a,int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    CVector operator + (const CVector&);
};

CVector CVector::operator+ (const CVector& param) {
  CVector temp;
  cout << " x: -> " << temp.x << " <-";
  cout << " y: -> " << temp.y << " <-\n";
  temp.x = x + param.x;
  temp.y = y + param.y;
  return temp;
}

int main () {
  CVector foo (3,1);
  CVector bar (1,2);
  CVector result;
  result = foo + bar;
  cout << result.x << ',' << result.y << '\n';
  return 0;
}

Result: x:-> 2 <- y: -> 1 <-
        4,3
```

Answer (score 3):

Member variables are constructed but not *initialized* by default. That means a default-constructed `CVector` object will have uninitialized `x` and `y` members, with *indeterminate* values.

Since you print those indeterminate values you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want the default constructor to set specific values (like e.g. zero) then you have to do it explicitly (for example in a constructor initializer list):

```
CVector () : x(0), y(0) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Some programmer dude stated, you can also use a default initialization within a multi-arg constructor:

```
CVector (int a = 0, int b = 0) : x(a), y(b) {}
```

in the event that you made a default CVector() it will always set the members to 0 but you can still accomplish CVector(5,5) with the same constructor.